# drupal 7 adding custom cck field in html.tpl.php head

Tags: drupal-7, cck, head, meta

I need to add a custom base href, I have a organic groups multisite setup. I have a field field_site_url which renders the URL correctly how would I get this to print

I did this but it doesnt work
base href="what do i put here" target="_blank"

Any ideas please
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I get CCK / fields data into html.tpl.php in d7 by using a preprocess function in template.php:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
 $node = menu_get_object();
  if($node)
  {
     $variables['myfield'] = $node->field_myfield['und'][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

This sets up a $myfield variable you can output in html.tpl.php :

```
echo $myfield;
```